# Wrong characters received with Bluetooth Mate Gold using Software Serial

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, bluetooth, softwareserial

I have a **Bluetooth device** from Sparkfun which I would like to use with the **Arduino Mega**. If I connect the module via the hardware serial pin everything works fine but when I use other pins like 12 and 13 with **SoftwareSerial**, the communication doesn't work as expected.

**THE CODE**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int bluetoothTx = 12;
int bluetoothRx = 13;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(115200);
  bluetooth.print("$$$");
  delay(100);
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available())
  {
    char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read(); 
    Serial.print(" Receiving: ");
    Serial.println(toSend);
  }

  //Read from usb serial to bluetooth
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char modeS = Serial.read(); 
    Serial.print(" Writing Blu: ");
    Serial.println(modeS);
    bluetooth.print(modeS);
  }
}
```

I'm using an Android App (BlueTerm) to test the communication.

Here is what I get when sending a letter from Android to Arduino.

```
 Receiving: ÿ
 Receiving: ÿ
 Receiving: ÿ
 Receiving: ÿ
 Writing Blu: d
 Writing Blu: d
 Writing Blu: d
```

I'm not able to receive anything from the Arduino.

I've tried decreasing the baudrate but nothing changed. Do you have any advice?

**Update**

I have tried without the following lines but nothing changed... It seems that the module can be used only with the hardware serial pins 0 and 1... It's a shame

```
bluetooth.print("$$$");
delay(100);
bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");
bluetooth.begin(9600);
```

Comment: What character are you sending from the Android App that is being received as 'ÿ'?  Are you just echoing back the 'd'?

Comment: Every letter I send from the Android app is received as 'ÿ'. Then from Arduino serial monitor I press three times d and send.

Comment: Just making sure, because 'ÿ' is the same as 'd' if you use 2 bytes per character and reverse the bit ordering. Seemed really strange if that was the case.

Comment: Is it possible that since Software Serial doesn't work well with baudrates over 38600 then the lines used to change the rate: `bluetooth.print("$$$");
  delay(100);
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");
  bluetooth.begin(9600);` are not received by the module? If that was the case then I would have sent bytes @ 9600 to the module which has a default listening rate of 115200.

Comment: That was my next thought.  115200 is *really* pushing it for Software Serial.